# Setting Label and Text values with javascript-- getting Cannot set property of null error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC view where I am trying to set values of certain labels and textboxes in a javascript function.  I can set the label OR the textbox just fine, but if I try to do both, I end up getting a "Caanot Set Property of Null" error.  Here's my view:

```
<div id='content'>
    Id:<br />
    <label id="datasetId" style="width:140px" />
    <br />

    Label:<br />
    <input type="text" id="txtLabel" style="width:140px" />
    <br />
</div>
```

Then I have a button that calls a javascript function called editDataSet which in turn calls a js function called SetData():

```
<script>
    function editDataSet(e) {
        //some code
        SetData(existingRecord);
        //more code
    }

    function SetData(dataSet) {
        document.getElementById('datasetId').innerText = "test"; 
        document.getElementById('txtLabel').value = "3";//errors out here
    }
```

When I run this, I get the error, but if I comment out the line, it runs fine.  If I comment out the first line, and keep the second, it runs fine too.  So

```
    function SetData(dataSet) {
        //document.getElementById('datasetId').innerText = "test";
        document.getElementById('txtLabel').value = "3";//now it works
    }
```

works, as does

```
    function SetData(dataSet) {
        document.getElementById('datasetId').innerText = "test";
        //document.getElementById('txtLabel').value = "3";//this works too
    }
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<label>` tag requires a closing `</label>`.

`<label id="datasetId" style="width:140px" />` is invalid HTML.

[MDN docs on label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

```js
function setData() {
  document.getElementById('datasetId').innerText = "test";
  document.getElementById('txtLabel').value = "3";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setData()">Run Test</button>
<div id='content'>
  Id:<br />
  
  <!-- changed to valid label -->
  <label id="datasetId" style="width:140px"></label>
  
  <br /> Label:

  <br />
  <input type="text" id="txtLabel" style="width:140px" />
  <br />
</div>
```